# How to get specific value from serialized array?

Tags: php, arrays

Im having a hard time digging how can I get the specific value on this serialized array:

`a:8:{s:13:"store_address";s:0:"";s:14:"country_select";s:2:"PH";s:13:"region_select";s:3:"MLA";s:10:"aboutstore";s:339:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eleifend turpis at arcu luctus placerat. Duis rhoncus auctor tincidunt. Aenean id nisi tortor, hendrerit sagittis elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam nibh massa, consectetur vel ultrices a, rhoncus at lectus.";s:16:"year_established";s:0:"";s:14:"contact_number";s:0:"";s:13:"facebook_page";s:0:"";s:12:"twitter_page";s:0:"";}`

For example I want to get the `aboutstore` value.. How to get this specific value?

Comment: you  serialize an array for  storing or passing, then unserialize when you want to access it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, you need to [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize) the data, then you can access it as an associative array:

```
$data = unserialize($your_string_of_serialized_data);

echo $data['aboutstore'];
```